# Python and Django request context error

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up a Django site that was transferred over to me and I've hit a strange error. This is only happening on the pages that call the template code below. I've tried removing the template call and the application just returns a 500 error. Has anyone ever seen something like this or possibly be able to suggest a method of further troubleshooting? Ubuntu12, Apache2, MySQL, Mod_Python, Python 2.7, Django 1.4

Stack Trace:

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

ProcessId:      8770
Interpreter:    'ip-10-245-86-33.ec2.internal'

ServerName:     'ip-10-245-86-33.ec2.internal'
DocumentRoot:   '/home/public_html/site'

URI:            '/location/index.html'
Location:       '/'
Directory:      None
Filename:       '/home/public_html/site/apache/django.wsgi'
PathInfo:       '/location/index.html'

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'django.core.handlers.modpython'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
    result = object(arg)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 180, in handler
    return ModPythonHandler()(req)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 158, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 33, in server_error
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({})))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1107, in render
    return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

  File "/home/public_html/site/asite/templatetags/meta_extras.py", line 35, in meta_url_reverse
    host = context["request"].get_host();

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'request'
```

Template Code:

```
{% block meta %}
    {% load meta_extras %}
    {% meta_title flatpage.title %}
    {% meta_description flatpage.content %}
    {% meta_url_reverse "asite_flatpage" flatpage.url %}
    {% block meta_image %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Offending Function Call:

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader_tags import register
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.template.context import Context

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def meta_url_reverse(context,args, pk=None):
    if pk is not None:
        url = reverse_lazy(args,args=[pk]);
    else:
        url = reverse_lazy(args);


    host = context["request"].get_host();
    if context["request"].is_secure():
        protocol = "https"
    else:
        protocol = "http"


    return "<link rel='canonical' href='{2}://{1}{0}'></link><meta property='og:url' content='{2}://{1}{0}' />".format(url,host,protocol)
```

Comment: Does django not already have a `reverse` function for urls?

Comment: What is there error? why are you using `reverse_lazy`? What is `flat page.url`?

Comment: Please include the stack trace here to set context for future visitors, also, please format your code properly.

Comment: You should use `build_absolute_uri` instead of doing that manually.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! My python skills aren't so great and I didn't write this code I just received it to set up, so I'm not sure why it does anything. Right now I just want to get it running, there's probably going to be a rewrite in the future anyway.

Comment: I'm not seeing flatpage.url being defined anywhere in the app. I'm not even sure why this code is vital as it only seems to be generating META tags. Removing it just displays a 500 error. May be that's a separate issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a `KeyError` complaining that the key `request` is not available to the context.

Make sure your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` includes [`django.core.context.processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request), or are explicitly adding it to the context in the view that is rendering the template.

== EDIT ==

If this is present in the settings, then you also need to make sure that the view itself is returning a `RequestContext` rather than `Context`.

Comment: I checked and it does:
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
  "django.core.context_processors.debug",
  "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
  "django.core.context_processors.media",
  "django.core.context_processors.request",
)